# Using recursion to populate arrays, without implementing method overloading?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, overloading

Is there a way to use recursion to populate arrays, without implementing method overloading? I want to build a method that takes only an int as argument, and returns an array. The only solution I have thought of is using method overloading; the function that takes int as argument builds the array and passes both the array and the int to the second function, which takes both the int and the array as arguments and implements the actual recursion.

Here is an example:

```
public static int[] recursiveBuilder(int depth, int[] anArray){
    // Base case:
    if (depth < 0){
        return anArray;
    }
    // Recursion:
    else{
        anArray[depth] = depth;
        depth--;
        return recursiveBuilder(depth, anArray);
    }
}

public static int[] recursiveBuilder(int depth){
    return recursiveBuilder(depth, new int[depth + 1]);
}
```

If I declare the array in the recursive part of the overloading, the array would get initialized every time the recursion is called, so I used a second function to declare the array.

Is this approach considered good? Efficient? Is there a way to implement this dynamic in only one method?

Comment: If this is a school assignment, your implementation is not necessarily meant to be efficient, but rather to demonstrate a technique or concept.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is not a school assignment. It would be awesome if it was, but I don't have the resources to make it possible ;) . I'm learning Java, and as part of the experience I'm building an open-source library (music and synthesis related). I got to a point where recursion was the answer. That answer induced more questions, and this is one of them.

Comment: Not to be contrary, but in applications such as yours, iteration is generally the order of the day (it being more efficient than recursion for near real-time applications).  Every recursive solution has an iterative counterpart, so it seems unlikely that recursion is the tool of choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Very commonly, a recursive solution requires two methods. The top method is called with the externally meaningful arguments, does any required set-up, and calls the recursive method. The recursive method takes additional arguments.

For example, a recursive binary search may have a top method that that takes as parameters only the probe and a reference to the array. The recursive method also takes a start and end index, so that it can limit itself to a slice of the array.

Java programs usually have a lot of small methods, and Java implementations are designed to handle that. If you can make your code be clear and work with two methods, go with two methods and move on to the next thing.